# What properties can we check to investigate geometric multiplicity of lowest Eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, what methods are there to check whether its lowest eigenvalue has or has not geometric multiplicity of 1? I mean, how can we check whether there is more than one linearly independent solution $x$ for $(A - \lambda_\text{min} I) x = 0$?

Is that even possible without actually knowing $A$? Are there any properties of $A$ that tell something about the dimensionality of the eigenspace of $\lambda_\text{min}$, so one could examine those?

In case it isn't possible: Is it possible, if we know $\lambda_\text{min}$, e.g. $\lambda_\text{min} = 0$?

Comment: The methods you need are methods which are capable of finding the nullspace (or kernel) of $A$. And yes, you do need to know $A$.

Comment: @5xum: There is no way of investigating this by only knowing the structure of $A$, i.e. its rank, the matrices it is a product of, ...?